# Using JkMount in a LocationMatch directive in Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-jk

I'm on Debian Wheezy with Apache 2.2.2.
I previously had all requests for a `VirtualHost` forwarding to Tomcat using:

```
JkMount / ajp13_worker
JkMount /* ajp13_worker
```

Now, I want to exclude one particular URL prefix `foo` from this setup, but otherwise preserve it.  I tried using a `LocationMatch` directive as follows:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!foo)">
    # JkMount commands
</LocationMatch>
```

If used as is, I get the following error message:

```
JkMount can not have a path when defined in a location
```

But if I try to use `JkMount ajp13_worker` then I get the error message:

```
JkMount context should start with /
```

How can I get the correct behavior only for URLs not starting with `/foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to JkMount:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!foo)">
   SetHandler jakarta-servlet
   SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13_worker
</LocationMatch>
```